# navigation stack vs my node

Tags: ros, navigation, subscribe, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo!

Is it possible to subscribe to user node from base_local_planner?

I'm trying to experiment with obstacle avoidance perfomance of my robot by integrating my emergency stop node that set a flag if an obstacle appears in it's field of view (narrow segment). Then given that flag I want to throw a banch of trajectories (which lie in this segment), generated by createTrajectories() function in base_local_planner package. I wonder if it's possible somehow to subscribe to this node so base-local_planner could use this flag.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48462/navigation-stack-vs-my-node/) by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 338 on 2012-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-16**:
What do you mean? Which data do you want to subscribe to or what functionality do you want to provide by your own node? Please be more specific.

**Comment by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on 2012-11-16**:
Sure. I'm trying to experiment with obstacle avoidance perfomance of my robot by integrating  my emergency stop node that set a flag if an obstacle appears in it's field of view (narrow segment). Then given that flag I want to throw a banch of trajectories, generated by createTrajectories() function

**Comment by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on 2012-11-16**:
... in base_local_planner package (which lie in this segment). I wonder if it's possible somehow to subscribe to this node so base-local_planner could use this flag.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-16**:
For such an update to the question, it's best to **edit** your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default `base_local_planner` node does not provide any topic-based interfaces to achieve what you want in a clean way. I suggest to fork it and add the functionality you need. The whole plugin is not that much code so adding new functionality should not be too hard.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1